# How to extract minimum and maximum time from a table in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

In a table that contains the Employee ID of every employee, the login time and the logout time for each employee, I need to extract the minimum from login time and maximum from logout time for each day. The problem is that every day an employee can login and logout multiple times. So, we have sample data that looks something like this,

```
 NAME     EMPID         LOGIN TIME         LOGOUT TIME 
user1       37      16-JAN-12 03.07.37  16-JAN-12 03.07.44
user5       21      16-JAN-12 02.00.36  16-JAN-12 04.45.34
user3       12      16-JAN-12 05.35.35  16-JAN-12 06.39.57
user3       40      16-JAN-12 02.54.13  16-JAN-12 07.12.16
user4       33      16-JAN-12 07.29.43  16-JAN-12 07.59.42
user1       40      16-JAN-12 07.12.39  16-JAN-12 07.59.50
user3       30      16-JAN-12 11.30.50  16-JAN-12 08.02.42
user990     31      17-JAN-12 11.46.12  17-JAN-12 01.46.13
user29      23      17-JAN-12 10.39.18  17-JAN-12 05.00.02
user20      21      17-JAN-12 04.59.37  17-JAN-12 05.00.17
user990     40      17-JAN-12 10.55.48  17-JAN-12 05.00.50
user4       23      17-JAN-12 05.00.11  17-JAN-12 05.01.08
user4       21      17-JAN-12 04.59.37  17-JAN-12 05.01.21
```

I tried this. It is working for only one day,

```
SELECT username, MIN(login_time), MAX(logout_time)
FROM Table_Name
WHERE trunc(login_time) = '19-JAN-12'
GROUP BY username;
```

This gives me the following result for the date I've entered. This is what I want for every date,

```
NAME

user1   19-JAN-12 11.00.26  19-JAN-12 08.00.53
user3   19-JAN-12 11.05.53  19-JAN-12 11.36.02
user29  19-JAN-12 09.49.32  19-JAN-12 06.48.08
user990 19-JAN-12 10.59.59  19-JAN-12 08.11.15
use23   19-JAN-12 06.40.36  19-JAN-12 08.36.07
user43  19-JAN-12 11.23.05  19-JAN-12 08.28.02
user89  19-JAN-12 02.38.54  19-JAN-12 07.28.02
user4   19-JAN-12 01.24.09  19-JAN-12 06.01.07
user7   19-JAN-12 03.29.17  19-JAN-12 08.34.02
user9   19-JAN-12 09.42.13  19-JAN-12 06.35.54
```

Comment: Why the -1? What crime did I commit? :)

Comment: I didn't downrate you, but you can guess by the number of (wrong) answers that your question was a bit unclear. Your edit improved it a lot, but still you have 16-JAN in your input data and 19-JAN in your desired output data?

Comment: I have the results that I wanted. Thanks to you. What I have is one record for every user for every date that tells about the minimum login time and maximum logout time. In this case, login and logout date are the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT    username, TRUNC(login_time), min(login_time), max(logout_time)
  FROM table_name
 GROUP BY username, TRUNC(login_time)
 ORDER BY username, TRUNC(login_time);
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be as simple as:

```
SELECT TRUNC(LOGIN_TIME]),NAME, EMPID, MIN(LOGIN_TIME), MAX(LOGOUT_TIME)
FROM Table_Name
GROUP BY TRUNC(LOGIN_TIME),NAME, EMPID
ORDER BY EMPID, TRUNC(LOGIN_TIME)
```

That will return one line per employee/day, earliest login and latest logout for that employee/day.

Comment: I've already tried this but this returns only one record per user from the whole database. I only need to find out daily minimum login time and maximum logout time for every username. I need this on a daily basis. Using **GROUP BY NAME, EMPID** just gives me the number of records = the number of usernames. I need it on a daily basis.

Answer (score 0):

In oracle:

```
SELECT NAME, TO_CHAR(IN_DT,'DD-MM-YYYY') as DT, TO_CHAR(MIN(IN_DT),'HH24:MI:SS')  as LOGIN, TO_CHAR(MAX(OUT_DT),'HH24:MI:SS') as LOGOUT FROM USER_LOG GROUP BY NAME, TO_CHAR(IN_DT,'DD-MM-YYYY');
```

[image]